# React, Redux Deleting an item on click deletes all items

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need fresh eyes on this. As I am slowly learning React and Redux i have run into a roadblock again.

```
/actions/items.js

export const DELETE_ITEM = "DELETE_ITEM"
export function deleteItem(id) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_ITEM,
    id
  }
}
```

/components/Item.jsx

```
export default class Item extends React.Component {

renderDelete = () => {
    return <button onClick={this.props.onDelete}>x</button>
  };

  renderItem = () => {
    const onDelete = this.props.onDelete

    return (
      <div onClick={this.edit}>
        <span>{this.props.text}</span> {onDelete ? this.renderDelete() : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

/components/Items.jsx

```
export default class Items extends React.Component {


  handleOnDelete = (id) => {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.deleteItem(id))
  }

  render() {
    const {items, onEdit, onDelete } = this.props

    return (
      <ul>{items.map(item =>
        <li key={item.id}>
          <Item
            id={item.id}
            text={item.text}
            onEdit={this.handleOnEdit}
            onDelete={this.handleOnDelete.bind(null, item.id)}
          />
        </li>
      )}</ul>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    items: state.items
  })
)(Items)
```

/reducers/items.js

```
case types.DELETE_ITEM:
  const filteredItems = state.filter((item) => {
    item.id !== action.id
  });

  return filteredItems
```

I'm not sure why clicking on `x` button to delete an item deletes all of them. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not return value in filter in your reducers.

Your should add `return`:

```
const filteredItems = state.filter((item) => {
  return item.id !== action.id;
});
```

Or use short version, without brackets:

```
const filteredItems = state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.id);
```

Comment: Ah good point. I had it like this before     case types.DELETE_ITEM:
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.id );
but ended up changing for some reason. Thanks Aleksandr